# Check if items are in a dictionary and are true using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I receive a JSON dictionary, and I want to check if certain keys are present **and are true**.

I check whether they're present using `all(i in incoming_json for i in ['title', 'code', 'university', 'lecturer'])`, but I'm stuck with checking if they're true.

I tried `all(i in incoming_json and True for i in ['title', 'code', 'university', 'lecturer'])` and `all(i in incoming_json for i in ['title', 'code', 'university', 'lecturer'] if i)`, but they don't seem to make any difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Example JSON:

`{title: "Example title", code: "1234", university: "2", lecturer: "John Doe"}`

Clarification: I only need to know if they're truthy or falsy.

Edit: thanks for the responses, I could've accepted any of them, but I accepted the one that explained what I did wrong.

Comment: include the json you are recieving

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and True` just checks that .. well, nothing, since `True` is `True`. `i in incoming_json and incoming_json[i]` would check that the value of the key represented in `incoming_json` is True as well (or a value evaluated as `True`).

If you actually want to check for the boolean value `True` (and not `1` etc.), use `incoming_json[i] is True`.

Comment: I got many excellent responses, but this answers my question the best.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `incoming_json.get(i)` which will return the value of the key or `None` if it doesn't exist as the following:

```
all(incoming_json.get(i) for i in ['title', 'code', 'university', 'lecturer'])
```

This will return `False` only if the value doesn't exist in the dictionary or if the value is `False`

Comment: Or just `incoming_json.get(i)`, since `None` is falsy.

Comment: @ekhumoro True :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
l = ['title', 'code', 'university', 'lecturer']
d = {title: "Example title", code: "1234", university: "2", lecturer: "John Doe"}

new_l = [i for i in l if i in d and d[i]]
```

Comment: `and i` is testing the keys, and the OP wants to test the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
incoming_json = {"title": "Example title", "code": "1234", "university": "2", "lecturer": "John Doe"} # the json

keys = ['title', 'code', 'university', 'lecturer'] # the keys

test = all(i in incoming_json and incoming_json[i] for i in keys) # if key in json keys and it's truthy

print(test) # True
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  `all` and `and` short-circuit as well.  Why add three `not`s?

Comment: @DSM yes, and I remember reading that since all and any are functions, all the arguments will be evaluated anyway, so any or all, just the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
all(incoming_json[i] if i in incoming_json else False for i in ['title', 'code', 'university', 'lecturer'])
```